# how to Populate following reqirement

Tags: talend

Populate the time_dim with the following fields

```
TIME_DIM_ID,   DATE,    DAY,  MONTH_ID,MONTH,MONTH_SEQ,WEEK_ID, WEEK_DESC
20140522,   5/22/2014, Thursday,201405,May, 5,    201420,      19-May-2014 to 23-May-2014
```

You should get starting year as input and no of years as input and has populate starting from the starting year to the input year+no of years.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? And what have you tried so far? Only thing I could understand is that you will get starting year and number of years as input. But what is the expected output?

Comment: Your question is not clear !